# "Version string empty" error in gprestore in greenplum

Tags: database-administration, greenplum

I am trying to restore a database in greenplum with gprestore using following command:

```
gprestore --backup-dir /data/greenplum/gpbackups/  --timestamp 20200511110837 --redirect-db restoredDB
```

But I am facing following error:

```
restore status:      Failure
restore error:       Version string empty
```

Can anyone help me regarding what can be the possible cause of this issue ?

Version info:

```
gpbackup version 1.17.0+dev.45.g697096e
PostgreSQL 9.4.24 (Greenplum Database 6.3.0 build commit:77aa1b6e4486adbaede9f5f2864a04fc3a512e93)
```

Comment: syntax seems to be correct but there is some other issue I guess

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more detail:

- Version of Greenplum
- Version of gpbackup/gprestore utilities.

This will help us troubleshoot.

Thanks

Comment: Please find below
gpbackup version 1.17.0+dev.45.g697096e

PostgreSQL 9.4.24 (Greenplum Database 6.3.0 build
 commit:77aa1b6e4486adbaede9f5f2864a04fc3a512e93)